# What would be the equivalent of following code in .hbs file

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I was working on a project involving node, mongoose, handlebars, express. What would be the equivalent of the following code in handlebars?

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getExams()">
 <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Exams</h3>
 </div>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="exam in exams">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>{{exam.examName}}</h4>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/exams/details/{{exam._id}}">View Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display all the rows of the output of the following function in my model.

```
module.exports.getExams = (callback, limit) => {
Exam.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node.js, when you're rendering :
`res.render('your view'),{exams:exams}`
In handlebars :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Exams</h3>
 </div>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="row">
 {{#each exams}}
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>{{examName}}</h4>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/exams/details/{{_id}}">View Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @SanSolo, but how do I call my function getExams() above as done by ng-init

Comment: You don't call the function. You pass exams to view like I have shown: `res.render('your view'),{exams:exams}`

Comment: @Saurabh please mark this as answer if it was useful